# Android Wearable -- Get package name of installed apps from smart phone

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

Is there a way to get the package names of all installed apps on my wearable device (watch) from my smart phone?  The restriction I have is that I cannot install anything on the wearable device itself.  I checked the NodeApi (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/NodeApi) which gives me *some* information about the wearable device but nothing with regards to the apps that are installed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you have anything installed on the wearable device?

Comment: I am working on a research project to see what kind of information can be retrieved simply by pairing two devices together.  Assuming that the same user owns both the smart phone and the wearable, I thought there would be more information that can be retrieved.